# SQL equivalent with MongoDB join and summary

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a subset of data

users with login dates etc. then a locations collection.

I want to get all users who logged in within a certain date range and then see how many did this per suburb

Now, in SQL I would join the tables, do some grouping and counting.

But in mongo, I'm not sure if the best approach is to use the aggregate functions or the map reduce functionality.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50174af210bb50b471000036"),
  "state_code" : "ACT",
  "suburb" : "Barton",
  "postcode" : 221,
  "loc" : [149.129623, -35.302345]
}
```

profiles look like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50176d9b539ba2903e000001"),
  "created_at" : ISODate("2012-07-31T05:31:07.538Z"),
  "gender" : "female",
  "first_name" : "Marge",
  "last_name" : "Simpson",
  "location_id" : ObjectId("50174af210bb50b471000235"),
  "s_location_name" : "Surry Hills (NSW)",
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-10-18T23:29:54.979Z"),
  "user_id" : ObjectId("50176c2510bb50a618000002")
}
```

and users has the last login

```
{   "_id" : ObjectId("50176c2510bb50a618000002"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2012-07-31T03:09:47.363Z"),
    "last_sign_in_at" : ISODate("2012-10-08T04:56:53.751Z"),
   "updated_at" : ISODate("2012-10-30T03:52:33.976Z")
}
```

What I want is

Melbourne X users signed up within a date range

So SQL pseudo code would be

```
select suburb, count(*) 
from user 
where last_login between x and y 
group by suburb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made the classical mistake here of designing your data model for the data (like you would do for a relational database), and not the date usage. Just like any other operation in MongoDB, neither the Aggregation Framework or Map/Reduce, can be done on more than one collection.

In this case, I would probably merge the profile and user collections, they don't seem to be too useful to have separate anyway. Then secondly, if the suburb in the locations collection is unique, just like its _id, then you should make the _id the value of suburb and not some made-up Object IDs. If it's suburb + state_code that's unique, make that the _id field. In MongoDB, _id fields can have any type. If the _id is then the value, then your users/profiles collection can use the value (hopefully just the suburb name) for location_id (renamed as location_suburb f.e.) and you then have a schema design that you can group with:

```
db.users.aggregate( { $group: { _id: location_suburb, count: { $sum: 1 } } } );
```

As a reminder: Even though you MongoDB is schema-free, it doesn't mean that you don't need to design your schema.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you can't do this. Everything cant be stored in a single collection, there are going to be edge cases where you wish to query that wasn't in the original design.

Comment: You really can't do operations on more than one collection at the same time. If you want that, you will need to do it in your applications.